# hive: split a row into multiple rows at one minute interval between two dates in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I've a hive table 'driver_time_stats' with columns slot_id, number_of_drivers, slot_start_time and slot_end_time.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
slot_id | number_of_drivers | slot_start_time     | slot_end_time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 5                 | 2018-01-01 09:30:00 | 2018-01-01 10:00:00
2       | 8                 | 2018-01-01 10:30:00 | 2018-01-01 11:00:00
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Desired output: each row should be splitter into multiple rows at 1 minute interval between slot_start_time & slot_end_time.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
slot_id | number_of_drivers | slot_start_time     | slot_end_time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 5                 | 2018-01-01 09:30:00 | 2018-01-01 09:31:00
1       | 5                 | 2018-01-01 09:31:00 | 2018-01-01 09:32:00
.
.
.
1       | 5                 | 2018-01-01 09:59:00 | 2018-01-01 10:00:00

2       | 8                 | 2018-01-01 10:30:00 | 2018-01-01 10:31:00
2       | 8                 | 2018-01-01 10:31:00 | 2018-01-01 10:32:00
.
.
.
2       | 8                 | 2018-01-01 10:59:00 | 2018-01-01 11:00:00

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I was using lateral view, posexplode  e.t.c functions but couldn't able to do it. Can anyone help me here ? in other way, I was trying to slice a record into multiple records at one minute interval in hive. I was able to achieve it in presto using UNNEST, but I want the solution in hive only as out ETLs built on hive.

-Nash

Answer (score 0):

well, I could able to find the answer with the help of my friend Henry, posting the same here so that it can help others searching for a solution to similar problem. below code snipped gives you a guidance. you can tweak it according to your need.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(st) + pe.i*60) FROM (
  select '2018-01-12 09:00:00' as st, '2018-01-12 11:30:00' as en) t
  lateral VIEW
  posexplode(split(
  space(cast(floor((unix_timestamp(t.en)-unix_timestamp(t.st))/60) as INT)), ' ')) pe as i, x
```